# To display message "products not found" if no search products exists, in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I want to display **products not found** if **no product exists in  database**. how to do in `products_controller.rb` **else condition** to get this?

**application.html**

```
<div class="input-group search-block">
    <%= form_tag products_path, :method => "get",:validate => true, html: {class: "navbar-form navbar-left form-width col-xs-6"} do %>
    <div class="input-append">
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search],  placeholder: "Search Products" , class: "form-control" %>
    <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-info home_searchbar_btn" type="submit"><span class="fa fa-search"></span></button>
    </div></div>
    <% end %> 
</div>
```

**products_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @products = Product.all
  if params[:search]
     @products = Product.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
  else
     @products = Product.order("created_at DESC")
  end
end
```

**product.rb**

```
def self.search(search)
   where("title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?","%#{search.strip}%","%#{search.strip}%")
  end
end
```

Comment: Try `flash[:error] = "Products not found" if @products.blank?` in the `else` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am not wrong, you are showing your successful search result in your `index.html.erb` of your products module. You are passing searched result into `@products` object. So in your `index.html.erb` file your can show message like *Result not found* like,

```
  <% if (@products) %>
    <% if (@products.empty?) %>
      <p>No product found.</p>
    <% else %>
      <% @products.each do |product| %>  
        <p><%= link_to "#{product.name}", product %></p>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
 <% else %>
   <p>Use the search form to search for product.</p>
 <% end %>
```